Replace all instances of a character, but only within matching strings
I have a data file in weird foramt that I'm trying to import and wrangle into R. The file is like a CSV in that values are comma delimited. However, there are also text strings containing commas that shouldn't be interpreted as delimiters.
The problem is, there is no use of quotes for individual elements. In the proprietary software, text strings containing non-delimiting commas are bounded by special, non-ASCII characters, which I'm guessing is how that software determines which commas not to use as delimiters.
I've figured out how to replace the non-ASCII characters with ASCII characters, to make it easier to work with in R. But, I still haven't figured out how to correctly split the text.
My current approach is to replace all the non-delimiting commas with another symbol (say, a semicolon) and then use strsplit for the commas. But, I haven't figured out how to replace the non-delimiting commas with semicolons.
For data privacy reasons, I'll create a dummy text string to work with here:
my_string <- "1,2,3,4,NONASCIIsome text, hereNONASCII,7,8,9,NONASCII,more, pesky, commas,NONASCII,10,11"

My desired output:
 [1] "1"                    "2"                    "3"                    "4"                   
 [5] "some text; here"      "7"                    "8"                    "9"                   
 [9] ";more; pesky; commas;" "10"                   "11" 

If I run strsplit as-is (after removing the "NONASCII"), I'd get something like this, which is not what I want:
[1] "1"         "2"         "3"         "4"         "some text" " here"     "7"         "8"         "9"        
[10] ""          "more"      " pesky"    " commas"   ""          "10"        "11" 


I'm not sure if gsub is the best function to use for this, but I've figured out how to at least match the problematic strings with regex:
my_string2 <- gsub("NONASCII(.*?)NONASCII", "\\1", my_string)

That's about as far as I've gotten. The code above only gets rid of the "NONASCII", but it doesn't replace the non-delimiting commas with semicolons
If there's another approach that would work too, I'm all ears!

What is the non-ASCII character? There's no reason in particular why R couldn't split on this particular string as a delimiter just like the proprietary software.

@thelatemail It's actually not one single non-ASCII character but rather a few different ones that are used. Earlier in the script, I use iconv(x, from="latin1", to="ASCII", sub="NONASCII"), which converts the various non-ASCII characters to "NONASCII".

@lotus - My thinking was that you'd want to split on the non-ascii characters first, then split on the commas for the remaining/other strings. Replacing the non-ascii curly-quote character “” with 's for example only works assuming there's no such quotes ' in the string that was surrounded by the curly-quotes.

You can replace 'NONASCII' with quotes, scan the data in, and replace the commas with semicolons:
my_string |>
  gsub("NONASCII", "'", x = _) |>
  scan(text = _, sep = ",", what = character(), quiet = TRUE) |>
  gsub(",", ";", x = _)

 [1] "1"                     "2"                     "3"                    
 [4] "4"                     "some text; here"       "7"                    
 [7] "8"                     "9"                     ";more; pesky; commas;"
[10] "10"                    "11" 


Thank you! And actually, for my needs, the last gsub call is no longer needed, since the call to scan splits it up the way I need it to. Also, while it's not explicit in your code, it seems like your call to scan defaults to the arg quote="\'", thus excluding sections within single quotes from being subject to the comma separator. Is that correct?

As a more general note, I just noticed that my actual data also contain instances of the ' symbol used as apostrophe, which throws off the intended output of scan from what I want it to be. But that should be easy enough to take care of upstream with gsub.

@TaylanMorcol - that's correct by default scan() will detect both single and double quotes if the separator isn't a newline.  You can substitute the quoting character for something else (e.g. " or |) as long as it isn't already used in your data.  Also. you might get a better answer if you post a sample of the unmodified data.

Thanks for clarifying. I agree that the original, unmodified data would be ideal. For data privacy reasons, I decided to go with made-up data instead.

There is already a good answer -- in fact I was going  to post a nearly identical one but @lotus answered first; however, let me point out one other approach.
gsubfn is like gsub except it inputs the captured portion of the regular expression (the portion within parentheses) into the function specified in the second argument and replaces the entire match with that function's output.  The function can be specified by giving the body as the right hand side of a formula and any free variables are assumed to be input arguments -- here x.  Thus gsub is only applied between the markers after which we can use strsplit.
If my_string is a character vector rather than just a single string then omit the unlist() at the end so that we get a list of character vectors of parsed values.
library(gsubfn)

my_string |>
  gsubfn("NONASCII(.*?)NONASCII", ~ gsub(",", ";", x), x = _) |>
  strsplit(",") |>
  unlist()

giving
 [1] "1"                     "2"                     "3"                    
 [4] "4"                     "some text; here"       "7"                    
 [7] "8"                     "9"                     ";more; pesky; commas;"
[10] "10"         

Here is a base solution; however, it does involve 3 gsub calls and a zero width perl regexp.  It gives the same result as shown above.  Use characters other than { and } if those can appear in your data.
The key here is that the start and end NONASCII be different so first replace the start with { and the end with }. Then we can use the indicated regex to replace , within {...} only.  Finally remove the { and } we added.  Now we can split on , as before.
my_string |>
  gsub("NONASCII(.*?)NONASCII", "{\\1}", x = _) |>
  gsub(",(?=[^{}]*})", ";", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>
  gsub("[{}]", "", x = _) |>
  strsplit(",") |>
  unlist()

Note
Input as given in question:
my_string <- "1,2,3,4,NONASCIIsome text, hereNONASCII,7,8,9,NONASCII,more, pesky, commas,NONASCII,10,11"


Thanks for sharing this alterate solution. It's is closer to what I was originally imagining. Is there a way to accomplish the same task using only regex and, say gsub()? Or is this task outside the capabilities of regex?

In other words, could you also specify both the matching pattern AND the replacement using regex?

I have added a solution using only gsub and strsplit but it is substantially more complicated.
